# CSS positioning of tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip

I have a tooltip and when the user clicks on the field, the tooltip breaks the `td`'s width.

Is there any solutions to this?

I've a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yfM5T/

If you click on the password field the size of that `TD` increases. How can I keep the size of `TD` intact and show the tooltip?

Comment: are you sure it's the width? The width doesn't change when I try it.

Comment: yes...This is the width , don't care about the width...I just want to show the tooltip, if we want we can increase the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the tool in absolute position, top:0, left:0

then, with mootools or jquery, specify that when it appears, the tooltip's X and Y positions should be similar to the field's position + some extra space (the field's wisth, for example)

and don't forget to add a condition that moves the tooltip when someone resizes the screen.

With JQuery, here's an exemple (I don't use mootools, but I assume you can do the same) :

```
function placeTooltip() {
    $("#tooltip").css("left",$("#field").position().left + $("#field").width());
    $("#tooltip").css("top",$("#field").position().top - $("#tooltip").height());
}

//Places tooltip on page load
$(document).ready(function() {
    placeTooltip();
});

//Places tooltip on page resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    placeTooltip();
});

$("#field").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#tooltip").fadeIn("normal");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to `.tooltip`

```
position: absolute;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yfM5T/9/

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: absolute;` to your `.tooltip` class. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yfM5T/8/

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:absolute;` (css) to the tooltip.
If you want it to change the position (using top and left), you can give the container element (in your case the `<td>`) `position:relative;` and left and top of your tooltip will be positioned relative to the td (not the document body) and it won't break the layout.

Comment: Thanks, for the comment Currently my td have a height of 25 px, how can I make it hover over or something.

Comment: You don't need the third td, you can put the tooltip in the second column. I found this helpful when i studied positioning : http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/